# Grails project unable to resolve classes from locally developed java module

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea

Using grails 2.5.0 & IntelliJ 13.1.6.

I have a grails app where I am trying to use a locally developed java library built with gradle.

In the IntelliJ project, I have added the java library as a module and I can get at the library source, edit, and run gradle commands, etc.

However, my grails project, which uses the java library, throws "unable to resolve class" errors when compiling.  Errors thrown on the 'import' statements in my grails app classes.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because IntelliJ can see it doesn't mean Grails can. You'll likely need to throw a JAR into the lib folder of your grails app or you might have to look at publishing the JAR to a local repository and pull it in via the dependency mechanism in BuildConfig.

Comment: Understand about IntelliJ v. Grails.  I've tried adding the jar file as a library within IntelliJ, doesn't work.  I've tried several things through IntelliJ, none work.  I would have expected this to be easily done via IntelliJ, but not so much.  I know I can drop the generated jar file in the lib folder but was looking for an IntelliJ way to do it without using the old 'cp' command.

Comment: Put your jar into the `lib` directory. If Grails still cannot find it, rename the directory `.grails/2.5.0/projects/your-project-name` in your home directory. That worked for me when the jars in `lib` weren't found.

Comment: I was hoping to do this automatically through IntelliJ, but nothing worked.  What I ended up doing was creating a symbolic link within the lib directory to the jar file built in the other project.  So, I can modify code in the java library, create the jar file using gradle, then my grails app loads the new jar file with the changes.  Just disappointed that IntelliJ could not handle this without manually creating the sym link.